# How to find end and beginning of contiguous data range in Excel using c#?

Tags: c#, excel, ssis

I have several files I need to open automatically and then import via SSIS.
Problem is, the relevant range in each file is different, and does not necessarily start at cell A1.
When I open a file, press CTRL+End, it will activate the last cell in the sheet. Pressing CTRL+A will now select exactly the range that I need. So this is what I'm trying to automate.

I can implement the first part, of finding the last cell, with

```
worksheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
```

But I can't figure out how to mimic the Select All command, that's selecting only the adjacent cells with data.

Answer (score 1):

currentRegion did it!
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.currentregion

```
worksheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing).CurrentRegion;
```